# data not getting parsed as json in jquery auto complete plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, jquery-plugins

I want to implement auto complete feature in a rails application. I am using the jquery auto complete plugin.

I want to implement the auto complete feature for the following array.

```
  @testers = User.find_by_sql("select * from users where id in(select user_id from user_role_assignments where role_id in (select id from roles where name like 'Tester')) order by name").paginate(:page=>params[:page],:per_page=>30)
```

I want to pass this in json format to the .js file. I tried using  the below code code in my view file.But the auto complete is not populating the data.

```
= form.label :tester_tokens, "Testers" 
        = form.text_field :tester_tokens
        - @testers.each do |tester|
          %tr
            %td=tester.name
            %td=check_box_tag "release[tester_ids][]", tester.id, @release.is_tester_assigned(tester)
      //=will_paginate @testers

:javascript
var data="#{escape_javascript @testers.to_json}";    
= javascript_include_tag :defaults,:cache => true
```

My .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

$.parseJSON(data);
  alert (data);
 $('#release_tester_tokens').autocomplete({source:data}); 

 });
```

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're discarding the value returned by `$.parseJSON`.

```
$(function() {
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(data);
    $('#release_tester_tokens').autocomplete({source:data}); 
});
```

Comment: Hi Matt,Thanks for answering me.I changed it.Still it doesn't work for me

Comment: Hi Matt,I am not able to see the console output in IE. I tried giving it as an alert message.I am getting 2 alert msgs one with all the names and other as null

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information, like an [SSCCE](http://ssce.org). How about a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Other questions: What value of `data` does the browser see before parsing it? I don't even know how you'd have 2 alerts, since you haven't shown any code that uses more than 1 alert. What version of IE are you using? IE8+ has a console that will work with `console.log`, and `console.log` is generally much better for debugging than `alert`.

Comment: hi matt, the console output gives me this ,["aaloshious", "aarul", "aaziz", "abaher", "abain", "abalteanu", "abencz", "abennett", "abenoy", "aberkovich", "abhose", "abirchall", "abouchard", "abrezinov", "aburden", "aburt", "acar", "acarver", "acase", "acatana", "achandel", "achandrasekaran", "achaudhary", "achen", "agillera", "agrodzki", "agroisman", "agurusamy", "ahalimi", "ahamu", "ahan", "ahardie","dbrovkovich", "dbyron", "dcelestine", "dchacon", "dchapeskie", "dchappelle", "dcocca", "dcole", "dcostanzino", 1157 more...]

Comment: Is that before or after parsing it? That does not look like [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6223/discussion-between-ramya-and-m-ll)